# Number of ways of arranging 5 boys and 5 girls in a queue if Infront of each girl number of girls are more than or equal to the number of boys is

Tags: permutations

The number of ways of arranging 5 boys and 5 girls in a queue if infront of each girl number
of girls are more than or equal to the number of boys is

**My try:**

I am sure that first person should be a girl.

> G _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

Now second can be a girl or a boy. If it is a boy, then third should definitely be a girl.

> G G _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
> or
> G B G _ _ _ _ _ _ _

But I am not able to find out a systematic way to count all such possibilities. Can anyone please provide some hint.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number